# Is it possible to return a sub table from an sql query but also scan this table into a new set of rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

This is a function I have written to demonstrate what I would like to do.

The query is more than likley not accurate as I just wanted to see if someone could tell me if this is possible before I spend alot of time on it.

I have commented the code so it hopefully explains what I hope to achieve.

```
func (t *Timetable) getMergedIncidents(ctx context.Context, app *application.Application, rids []uint64, toc string, crs string) error {
    //statment that returns a nested list of results
    stmt := `select inci2.id, (inci1.rid, inci1.id) from incidents as inci1 left join incidents as inci2 on inci1.merge_id = inci2.id where inci2.rid = $1`
    rid := 1234567
    //get the rows of the query
    rows, err := app.DB.Client.QueryContext(ctx, stmt, rid)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // iterate over the original rows
    for rows.Next() {
        var id sql.NullInt64
        var subResult sql.Rows
        var subResults []int64
        //scan the nested query into a new rows
        err := rows.Scan(&id, subResult)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // iterate over the new rows
        for subResult.Next() {
            var id sql.NullInt64
            var rid sql.NullInt64

            err = subResult.Scan(&id, &rid)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            subResults = append(subResults, id.Int64, rid.Int64)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "sub table"?

Comment: If I understand your question, it has nothing at all to do with Go. And the term you want is "sub query".  See the PostgreSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-subquery.html

Comment: instead of having all the results return in a flat format like inci1.id | inci2.rid | inci2.id i would like the join to have multiple rows per 1 result i cant really demonstrate in the comment but something like inci1.id | ((inci2.rid | inci2.id),(inci1.id | inci2.rid | inci2.id),(inci1.id | inci2.rid | inci2.id))

Comment: ah ok a sub query, if i return a sub query can i scan it into a new sql.Rows ?

Comment: Please read the PostgreSQL documentation about it. It returns a set of rows, same as any other query.

Comment: One option would be, at the Go side of things, to utilize [multiple result sets](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_Query_multipleResultSets), it's not exactly what you're asking for, but it can do the same job in a slightly different way. The other option would be on the postgres side of things, which is to simply aggregate the sub-query's result into single column of some composite data type, like a json array for example, and decode it upon scanning.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make it much clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: With MySQL I'm using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function to aggregate the rows of the "sub query" into a column which I de-aggregate on the Go side. There are similar tools for PostgreSQL: https://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg

Comment: @GordonLinoff imagine I wants to get Lol posts by a user and want to left join all comments for each post but I don't want a repeated row of the post for each comment I just want post ->[comments]